# Renaming workers per requirements of Zeitwerk (Rails 5.2.3 to 6 upgrade)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some Sidekiq workers that have a naming convention of like `random_api_worker.rb` and have the class defined as `RandomAPIWorker` and it has always worked up until Rails 6. In other cases, I have the classes starting off as `class RandomAPIWorker` although it's in a few subdirectories, such as `app/workers/dir1/dir2/random_api_worker.rb`

I have added `config.autoloader = :classic` to my `application.rb` file, but this seems to only do the trick if I'm running everything in development. The minute I flip the `RAILS_ENV` to `production`, then it starts complaining about worker names.

This brings me to a two questions:

1. Isn't the `config.autoloader = :classic` supposed to ignore this, or am I misunderstanding how this works?
2. Is there a Zeitwerk script available that could essentially *upgrade* classic worker names in a proper format/hierarchy?
3. If #1 is false, is there another way to keep my workers with their same names and not have to worry about renaming them to meet the requirements of Zeitwerk?

Here's my `application.rb` file:

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Vspm
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 6.0
    config.autoload = :classic
    
    config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('app/workers/sampleworkers/**/')
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration can go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded after loading
    # the framework and any gems in your application. 
    config.enable_dependency_loading = true
    config.eager_load_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/custom/**/"]
    # Add images and subdirectories to asset pipeline
    config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/severity_icons/"
end
```

Here's one error (complains about the caps in one of the class names):

```
ubuntu@c567d17a6700:~/myapp/app$ RAILS_ENV=production rails zeitwerk:check
Hold on, I am eager loading the application.
expected file app/services/pdf_generator.rb to define constant PdfGenerator
```

Here's the class name defined in that file:

```
# app/services/pdf_generator.rb
class PDFGenerator
```

After fixing this, the next error complains about the directory hierarchy not being in the worker's class name:

```
ubuntu@c567d17a6700:~/myapp/app$ RAILS_ENV=production rails zeitwerk:check
Hold on, I am eager loading the application.
expected file app/workers/shared/random_name_worker.rb to define constant Shared::RandomNameWorker
```

Here's how the class is mentioned in that file:

```
# app/workers/shared/random_name_worker.rb
class RandomNameWorker
```

Comment: You are correct `autoloader = :classic` should/does cause it to ignore constant changes like that. Settings in `application.rb` can be overridden by environment. Have you checked `environments/production.rb` to see if it has a conflicting setting?

Comment: AFIK there's no auto-fixer for constants, but running `rails zeitwerk:check` will at least report all the conflicts in your application. That task will give an error when autoloading is set to `:classic` so you might also run it against production to see if it is really setting the loader to `:classic` or not in that environment.

Comment: I've checked production and don't see any conflicts there. However, I do have some `autoload_paths` and `eager_load_paths` that are below the :classic command. Not sure if the ordering here is a priority or not. Updated the post to provide more context.

Comment: I pasted your config into a scratch 6.1 app and it happily does `:classic` in all environments unless I specifically override the loader in `production.rb`. If you run `RAILS_ENV=production rails zeitwerk:check` does it give a message like 'please enable `:zeitwerk`'?

Comment: I'm on Rails 6.0, so not sure if there are any differences that would cause that. Whenever I run the check, it complains about "expecting app/workers/shared/random_name_worker.rb to define constant Shared::RandomNameWorker"

Comment: That's what it's supposed to do if the autoloader is `:zeitwerk`. It will tell you all the classes where there's a naming clash. But it also does mean that `:classic` mode is not getting enabled, because when it is that task doesn't run.

Comment: Yeah I think that's the part that's confusing for me and I can't quite pinpoint just yet. Assuming `:classic` ignores this, I'm not expecting to see it flag it as a problem if it's supposed to be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Isn't the config.autoloader = :classic supposed to ignore this, or am I misunderstanding how this works?

this setting config Rails back to `classic mode` loader on the whole app, so of course it'll ignore **structure name convenient**.

you could setup `autoload_paths` with `zeitwerk`, your problem is the way you add nested workers directories to `autoload_paths`

```rb
# NOT THIS
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('app/workers/sampleworkers/**/')

# SHOULD THIS
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('app/workers/sampleworkers/')

# OR THIS (if you want to use `**`)
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/workers/**/**"]

# REPLACE 
config.autoloader = :classic 
# BY 
config.load_defaults 6.0
```

> 2. Is there a Zeitwerk script available that could essentially upgrade classic worker names in a proper format/hierarchy?

i don't know whether there's a gem support that or not, i haven't seen so far, i do it manually, create module each sub directories, so your worker become something like this `Api_Worker::Random`

```rb
# app/worker/api_worker.rb
module ApiWorker
end

# app/worker/api_worker/random.rb
module ApiWorker
 class Random
   include Sidekiq::Worker
 end
end
```

> 3. If #1 is false, is there another way to keep my workers with their same names and not have to worry about renaming them to meet the requirements of Zeitwerk?

As i said above, you could extend `autoload_paths` with `zeitwerk`

```rb
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/workers/**/**"]
```

and you still use the name `RandomAPIWorker`

Comment: Any chance you can clarify the first code block? I'm actually not quite sure what you're recommending altogether. However, I did replace the line containing `**` with the one without, and then removed the `:classic` line, keeping the `load_defaults` and my `check` still came back with naming errors (specifically a worker that has caps like RandomNameAPIWorker but has a file name of random_name_api_worker. Again, figured this would be ignored in the check since I have classic enabled (supposedly)

Comment: is your file path `app/workers/sampleworkers/random_name_api_worker.rb`?

Comment: Yep -- that's the correct file path and name, although its class name is RandomNameAPIWorker instead of RandomNameApiWorker.

Comment: could you show me the full message of the naming error ?

Comment: Updated the original post to contain the details. You'll notice that the first error complains about caps being in a class name, and the second one complains about it not being named properly

Comment: i guess class `RandomNameWorker` belongs to module `Shared`, right ? so in this case you no need to extend `autoload_paths` anymore (remove it on application file). you're playing the `zeitwerk` rule. Just make sure that there's a `module Shared` app/workers/shared.rb

Comment: I don't have a module called Shared unless that's something Ruby creates on its own (not familiar with this). I just don't have anything explicitly defined named Shared.

Comment: in that case, your class name should be `Shared::RandomNameWorker`, no need to change file name or directories structure, but you have to change the class name, i don't know how to keep your original class name in this scenario.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks a lot -- I think this is the clarification I was looking for. I assumed the `:classic` attribute would mean I can keep my class names the way they were.

Comment: @LewlSauce But you could extend `autoload_paths`: `config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/workers/**/**"]` and use class name `RandomNameWorker` (no prefix `Shared::`), right ?

Comment: Tried doing that as well, but it still complains the same way with the same error, unfortunately.